# Component rendering just the element name not the template contents

Tags: vuejs2

I have just started with Vue and am having an issue where the component isn't rendering for me.

```
<template>

    <div>
        <GalleryCollectionBlueBottles />
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import GalleryCollectionBlueBottles from '@/components/collections/GalleryCollectionBlueBottles.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'GalleryCollections'
    }

</script>
```

When I inspect the page in a browser all I see is an element with the component name, not the contents of the component as usual.

The component above is called `GalleryCollections` and the component I'm importing is called `GalleryCollectionBlueBottles`.

Hope someone can help, also hoping this is something simple I've overlooked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also declare the component inside your script tag within the keyword **components{ ... }** like;

```js
<script>
import GalleryCollectionBlueBottles from '@/components/collections/GalleryCollectionBlueBottles.vue'

export default {
  name: 'GalleryCollections',
  components: {
    GalleryCollectionBlueBottles
  }
}
</script>
```